# Windows Universal App Platform (UAP) SDK is missing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am getting this error on creating a C# Windows Universal App and got this error. The link is dead and I couldn't find an answer in other threads, or a download link for the missing SDK
[image]

I have already installed Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps (14.0.23121.00 D14OOB) and it didn't change a thing.

Comment: Have you figured out a solution, yet? I've been having the same stupid problem and after several repairs and modifications, have yet to arrive at a solution.

Comment: @not-inept can you check my answer to see if it works for you too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

after installing [Windows 10 Developer Tools](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/F/C/6FC19DBF-C223-41D0-835A-BD2155BC950D/VSToolsForWindows1C.exe) I didn't get this error anymore

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I suggest you repair or modify visual studio. You will need to be connected to enable visual studio download the required files. Its really strange and annoying that it has to do that. All needed files should have been included in the ISO.

Comment: I did it like 3 times (for almost 3 hours!). Now I have ~ 10 Gb of all dependencies on my computer and yet it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to lower target platform version.

1. Unload project to edit solution file (is already unloaded when error occures)
2. Change TargetPlatformVersion to minimum or other that u have installed.

TargetPlatformVersion:    10.0.10240.0
TargetPlatformMinVersion: 10.0.10240.0