# UWP App deployment issue with System.private.uri.dll

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am new to UWP development, facing following deployment error.

> Error : DEP3320 : Target device's operating system version does not
>   meet the application's minimum requirement. Minimum required operating
>   system is Windows 10.0.

I am using Lumia 930 device which has 8.1 OS. So is it possible to build and deploy my application on this device. I can't manage Windows 10 device right now. So is there any other way to built the UWP project. Currently I'm using the simulator for debugging purpose and it's going well but I can't able to deploy the project with simulator. It gives an error:

> Loading assembly
>   "C:\Users\ngulati.nuget\packages\System.Private.Uri\4.0.0\runtimes\win8-aot\lib\netcore50\System.Private.Uri.dll"
>   failed. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.File name:
>   'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: No, you can not run a UWP app on 8.1 OS, you should update your OS.

Comment: Yes I have updated the OS but still getting an error like  Loading assembly "C:\Users\**\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\runtimes\aot\lib\netcore50\mscorlib.dll" failed. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Object' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' because the parent does not exist.

Comment: Have you aware this issue ? The built run into debug mode successfully. But in release mode give an error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to install the [Visual Tools for Windows 10](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/F/C/6FC19DBF-C223-41D0-835A-BD2155BC950D/VSToolsForWindows1C.exe).
Thank's to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129769/windows-universal-app-platform-uap-sdk-is-missing-in-visual-studio-2015).

Comment: Any idea if there is an equivalent version for VS 2017?